# How to have MSBuild quiet output but with error/warning summary

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm simply trying to get no output from a build except the error/warning summary at the end.  Not exactly a demanding task.

The command line:

```
msbuild.exe /nologo /verbosity:quiet /consoleloggerparameters:summary project.sln
```

As described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx
It appears MSBuild isn't working as it should - there is no output at all.  with /verbosity:normal there is tonnes of output and a useful error/warning summary at the end, is there any way of just not seeing the noise?

MSBuild reports version 12.0.21005.1 as distributed with Studio Express 2013.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and see Minimal as the option you might be able to use? Am I wrong, did you try this one already?

Comment: Minimal shows all files as they are built, it's less noisy but also suppresses the error/warning summary which is quite a useful thing to have displayed.

Comment: *It appears MSBuild isn't working as it should* on the other hand, nowhere is described the output should be just the summary when you give it the parameters you show

Comment: stijn - The documentation in the link I provide is pretty clear, as I read it:  /clp:Summary. Show the error and warning summary at the end.

Comment: yes, that's true - but you are mixing it with setting verbosity, and the documentation about what that does exactly is rather vague (or maybe even non-existent, at least I never found a proper description) so you cannot just expect it to leave only the parts you want

Comment: I also wanted exactly what you want, but sadly "Summary" for msbuild does not mean what you think it means.  "Summary" in this case is the list of errors and warnings.  If your build had no errors or warnings, then "Summary" will print nothing.  A custom logger is your only option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is a set of options thet matches what you want exactly. But since you're on the commandline anyway, using findstr/grep/tail and the likes is always a good option. Here's an example using powershell to display the summary and what comes after it

```
powershell -Command "msbuild.exe /nologo project.sln |
                     Select-String 'Build succeeded|failed' -Context 0, 100"
```

Another possibility is to use a custom logger, which is not hard as it sounds at first and there are tons of examples on the net. Plus it has the benefit you can get any custom output you want. Here's code to replicate the summary:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;

public class CustomLogger : Logger
{
  private int warnings = 0;
  private int errors = 0;

  public override void Initialize( IEventSource eventSource )
  {
    eventSource.WarningRaised += ( s, e ) => ++warnings;
    eventSource.ErrorRaised += ( s, e ) => ++errors;
    eventSource.BuildFinished += ( s, e ) =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine( errors == 0 ? "Build succeeded." : "Build failed." );
      Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "    {0} Warning(s)", warnings ) );
      Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "    {0} Error(s)", errors ) );
    };
  }
}
```

Put this in a file CustomLogger.cs and compile it:

```
csc /t:library CustomLogger.cs /reference:Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll;Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
```

which creates a CustomLogger dll file. Now use it like this:

```
msbuild /nologo /logger:CustomLogger.dll /noconsolelogger project.sln
```

Comment: stijn - many thanks for the answer, as I said above it's not how I read the documentation but your answer works.  It just seems odd that it's necessary to use a custom logger to get this information, I would have thought that this is what everyone requires from a build system.

Comment: For something like log output I'd say person A wants X and person B wants Y and so on, so my guess is MsBuild wanted to find a middle ground (and that happens to be not what you want specifically) combined with customisation

Answer (score 23):

late to the party, but MSBuild has the option `/verbosity:quiet` now and it doesn't print out anything beside error and warnings.

```
    You can specify the following verbosity levels: 
    q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic]
```

Documentation source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: I'm using MSBuild from VS2019 and `/verbosity:quiet` has no affect at all for me

Comment: Updated MSBuild Reference link for 2022:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 20):

Use `/consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly` or `clp:ErrorsOnly` to solve your problem.

Comment: Beautiful! This worked for me in a Framework 4.6 project `msbuild ... /clp:ErrorsOnly`, and also .NET Core 3 `dotnet publish ... --clp:ErrorsOnly`

Answer (score 10):

[Obsolete:] <s>Use `/verbosity:minimal` instead.  This prints much less, but not nothing.</s>

Comment: `/verbosity:minimal` does not print errors and warnings summary

Comment: With "MSBuild version 17.6.3" above statement is wrong. `msbuild solution.sln /verbosity:minimal` **does** print errors and warnings.